# Flutter: Trying to highlight a ListTile using OnTap

Tags: database, flutter

I'm trying to figure out how to go about highlighting a selected ListTile so I only edit values of the highlighted Tiles from a Database.

Some contextual code in case it is needed.

User_List.dart

```
class UserList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserListState createState() => _UserListState();
}

class _UserListState extends State<UserList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final users = Provider.of<List<Camper>>(context) ?? [];

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: users.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index){
        return UserTile(user: users[index]);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The below is the code that I'm trying to get the OnTap working on.

User_Tile.dart

```
class UserTile extends StatelessWidget {

  final Camper user;
  UserTile({this.user});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
        child: Card(
          elevation: 10.0,
          color: Colors.blue[100],
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 6.0, 20.0, 0.0),
          child: ListTile(
            leading: Text('ID: ${user.camperID}'),
            title: Text(user.name),
            subtitle: Text(user.instrument),
            //Dense compacts the text together more
            dense: true,
            trailing: Text(user.band + ' Band'),

          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Most of my attempts at using onTap or onPressed were failing and I am not experienced enough with Flutter so I thought I'd ask here and see if anyone knew.

If you need more information from me please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `statefulwidget` instead of `statelesswidget`

```
class UserList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserListState createState() => _UserListState();
}

class _UserListState extends State<UserList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    int selectedIndex = 0;
    final users = Provider.of<List<Camper>>(context) ?? [];

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: users.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index){
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
          child: Card(
            elevation: 10.0,
            color: Colors.blue[100],
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 6.0, 20.0, 0.0),
            child: Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                  itemCount: users.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedIndex = index;
                        });
                      },
                      child: ListTile(
                        leading: Text('ID: ${users.camperID}'),
                        title: Text(users.name,style: TextStyle(
                            color: index == selectedIndex
                                ? Colors.white
                                : Colors.white60,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 24.0,
                            letterSpacing: 1.2),),
                        subtitle: Text(users.instrument),
                        //Dense compacts the text together more
                        dense: true,
                        trailing: Text(users.band + ' Band'),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When i use this code all my 'user' data turns to undefined. I forgot to add another part of my code to the question as I didn't think it was needed but have added it now if you want to take a look. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Seems that the data portions of my user data are now invalid. For instance, 'users.camperID' now has camperID coming up as an error. Not really sure why though and looking through everything it doesn't seem obvious to me why it would be creating errors now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping it in a gesturedetector?

Comment: I can add GestureDetector to it but I'm not sure how to go about highlighting it as a result of the tap.

Comment: Make it a stateful widget and when the gesture detector is tapped have it change a parameter from true to false and then call the set state function.

Comment: Also make sure you have the color evaluated based on that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to do this is by wrapping your `ListTile` inside of `ListView` and giving with ListTile property `onTap()` as without it there will be no material ripple effect and also you need to make your Listview elements shrinkwrap by adding `shrinkwrap: true` so it takes only required space n doesn't take all the space and you can give each of the ListTile item an ink property which can take different colors whichever you want. I know its too late for an answer but this is simplest way to do so which may help others,

try the code below,

```
ListView( shrinkWrap: true,
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {},
                  leading: Icon(
                    Icons.home,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  title: Text('Home'),
                ),],
            ),
```